# starting cassandra on windows 7 error the system can not find the path specified

Tags: windows, cassandra, config

I have tried to get cassandra working on windows 7. I followed the instructions from:
http://php-cms-job.blogspot.de/2012/09/how-to-install-cassandra-and-configure.html
I have double checked the steps of creating the folders and changing the yaml file but always get the message after running cassandra.bat:
Starting Cassandra Server
The System cannot find the Path Specified

I can not find which path exactly, any tips?

Comment: Put some `echo` statements into the start script to find out where it fails?

Comment: Go to your Cassandra log and see if it has more details on this failure.  You can find the log at the correct line in conf/log4j-server.properties .

Comment: thanks for your answers..I just did it from scratch this morning and it worked now after I installed it as a service based on instruction from this page:http://kimola.com/articles/cassandra-installation-on-windows-platform
and try to start it I get the following error: The cassandra service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function..

Comment: Again, Cassandra logs will describe the error in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra will fail to start with no logs if the values in 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\cassandra\Parameters\Java` are not correct.

For example, if the Jvm REG_SZ value is not pointing to the correct path for jvm.dll you will get a System event log Error with

> "The cassandra service terminated with the following service-specific error: Incorrect function".

You can find where java is with `>echo %JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: In my case I enabled logs with: -`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\cassandra\Parameters\Log\StdError` and saw that JVM wasn't being initialized, value was "auto", changed to the jvm.dll path and service now starts, or tries to. Something is happening with Cassandra now but that is another step.

Answer (score 2):

To any future Googlers, in my case the issue was that Cassandra had created the service using the 32-bit version of `prunsrv.exe`. To fix it, I manually replaced the 32-bit version with the 64-bit version (found inside the `amd64` folder).